# com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Unexpected element

Tags: salesforce, mule, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule-connector

Salesforce have announced that they will be retiring API versions 21 through to 30 in the Summer 23 release (June 2023).  After this date, any connections to Salesforce using one of these API versions will be unsuccessful. At the moment, we are using API version 28 to login to the instance of Salesforce and create the moving records.

We updated it from version 28.0 to 55.0, we are now getting this error.

com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Unexpected element.  Parser was expecting element 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:currencySymbol' but found 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:chatterExternal

Comment: Can you add details about the mule runtime version, salesforce connector version, authentication method you are using and the auth URL?

Comment: Mule runtime version - 3.5.0 CE, salesforce connector version - https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0

Comment: auth method and sf connector version?. Also do not add it in comments, please update them in your question

Answer (score 0):

The latest API version support by the latest release of the Mule 3.x Salesforce connector is 51. See the release notes for details on the compatible versions: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/salesforce-connector-release-notes#8-11-5

Having said that you will probably not be able to take advantage of newer versions of the connector without upgrading to a supported enterprise release of Mule since it is currently classified as a Select connector.

As a side note Mule 3.5.0 is a very old release that contains a lot of bugs and security vulnerabilities.